# When can using(new SomeThing()) { ... } safely GC the allocated but unnamed resource?

Tags: c#, mono, using

I fixed a bug in my Vsync library (used to be called Isis2), that centers on a disagreement between me and Mono over the semantics of the using clause.  In Vsync, I have lock-wrappers that bump the thread priority to avoid priority inversions (where a high priority thread could be waiting on a lock held by a low priority thread).  The code looks like this:

```
using(new LockAndElevate(myLock)) { ... code protected by myLock ... }
```

My understanding is that this is exactly equivalent to

```
try { ml = new LockAndElevate(myLock)); ... code ... } finally { ml.Dispose(); }
```

But in fact the mono garbage collector seems to conclude that there are no references to the locked object in my protected code (the first example where there is no variable used), and garbage collects it while still in the "protected" code block.  This behavior goes away when I change my code to:

```
using(var tmp = new LockAndElevate(myLock)) { ... code ... }
```

So here by adding a variable that I never reference, I prevent premature GC.  But semantically, they should be able to do a code analysis and realize that the tmp variable is not referenced, delete the "var tmp = " portion, at which point they might again incorrectly collect my wrapped lock prematurely.  Thus my fix worries me because a future compiler improvement to Mono could again break this logic.

Am I just wrong, or is this a mono compiler bug?

Comment: _"garbage collects it while still in the "protected" code block"_ - how do you determine this? Also, `Dispose()` will be called in a `finally` block, not a `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the catch and replaced with finally.  I detected it extremely painfully.  Vsync was throwing null pointer exceptions on these myLock objects, yet the objects themselves are static fields of a class that was long ago loaded, and were initialized by static initializers (for example, var myLock = new VsyncLock(...)).  We were baffled: how could they become null?  Eventually we realized that wrapper was being disposed and the references it had to the myLock object were nulled.  Then pinned this down to see that it happened while in the code block.  Very hard to trigger!

Comment: I think you'll have more luck creating a [mcve] and filing a bug report than with posting here. The code you show should not show the behavior you describe, there's not much SO can do about it if it does.

Comment: Agreed, and we tried, and haven't managed to do that.  As I said, this was insanely hard to pin down because it happens when you happen to be in the protected block, and so something has to trigger GC just then.  My code did reproduce this, hundreds of times, so we eventually worked out the cause.  But no idea if I could create an example.  Hence my principled question!  C# on .NET seems to agree with my semantic interpretation...

Comment: PS: I do think SO can (1) warn others, who will see this thread if facing a similar issue; (2) agree on what the semantics should be, so perhaps the Mono folks will then fix their compiler issue.  (3) give me the small thrill of having people agree with me on an SO issue posting...  if you do.

Comment: The C# spec is pretty clear in that `using (resource) statement` will be translated to (in short) `resource; try { statement } finally { resource.Dispose(); }`, meaning `resource` should not be disposed during the execution of `statement`, let alone be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks.  This is my feeling too.  I'll try and post it as a Mono bug (good luck to me, though, since I have no idea how to show them a minimal example)\

Comment: The C# 5 spec states that `resource-acquisition` within a `using` statement *requires* local variable(s) to be defined, in your case I do not see how the `resource` would have to held till after the block ends. Specifically the `usage` of a `resource` within the `acquisition, usage, and disposal` cycle

Comment: But then I would also need to use it, or the variable is an unused one that can be deleted, no?  So the logic forces me to write meaningless code to fool the compiler into thinking I used the variable too.  A good analysis would still sense that this was dead code and could be removed.  So that logic leads to "the using clause is useless"

Comment: By the same token, `new FooBar()` as a `resource` without assignment and usage is also 'dead code'... I would need to find the C# unit test for this feature and disassembly it but I am assuming it looks the same w/ or w/o an a resource `assignment`, but without `usage` I do not see why the runtime  would not be allowed to collect that object.

Comment: Indeed.  Which leads back to my interpretation, IMHO.

Comment: ;-) My interpretation is the opposite, without assignment during `resource-acquisition`, no object `Dispose` can ever be called as there is no local variable to use in the block's finalize. Need someone like Jon Skeet to interpret the spec since he is also a member that is working it.

Comment: Whether or not this is a bug -- it sounds like one, but appearances can be deceiving -- I would caution against this pattern. Disposables are intended to represent unmanaged resources that need to be cleaned up in order to politely release a resource for others to use, not to implement locking semantics. I would think of this as an "off label" use; if you want a construction that has try-finally semantics then why not use try-finally?

Comment: Yes, thought of that.  And might do it.  But then using is a useless language construct except for things like Window handles.  I guess I prefer the elegance of using, without an unneeded temporary variable: you have to agree that it does look a lot nicer.  But Eric, you are absolutely correct and indeed that would eliminate any debate on the semantics.

Comment: @SushiHangover If you don't provide a variable for the resource it'll still be stored in one, it's just that the variable isn't in scope in the body of the `using`.  The object still needs to be stored in a variable so that `Dispose` can be called on it in the `finally` though.

Comment: @Servy, that was precisely how I reasoned in the first place!

Comment: @Eric tell that to the ASP.NET MVC team, with their `using (@Html.BeginForm()) { ... }`, where `MvcForm.Dispose()` will print `</form>`... ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster, if you repost that as an answer I would vote it!

Comment: @CodeCaster: Drives me nuts. They did not ask me my opinion; I would have gladly given them one! :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, for those who might read this in the future I'll summarize what people have been saying:

- @EricLippert feels that my style of coding is not what was intended with the "using" statement and hence risky.  He recommends the (ugly) approach of using an explicit variable to hold the new resource and then a try-finally statement, which obviously would be safe and correct.
- @CodeCaster points to cases where Microsoft's own people have been using the same code style as me (like me, they take advantage of Dispose to trigger a cleanup action).  @EricLippert wishes they had checked with him first.
- The .NET C# compiler apparently doesn't garbage collect the resource until the application exits the using statement, whereas I have observed the Mono compiler to do so (but don't have a minimal reproducible example, which is frustrating for all concerned).  But there is a sense in which both behaviors are true to the C# specification.  In a subthread that someone seems to have deleted, it was pointed out that the C# specification seemingly discourages the coding style I used, even though Microsoft's internal people also employ "using" in the same way.
- A case can be made that in this respect the specification is incorrect.  Basically, a well-written compiler would detect and trim dead code.  Thus a compiler might notice that the resource allocated in the using statement isn't actually used (and might do so whether or not you declare a temporary variable), clean the code up, and eventually conclude that the using statement itself can be safely removed.  The two examples -- mine, where there are locking side-effects, and the ASP.NET example, where the inner block creates a web page that the finally statement writes to the output stream, illustrate the flaw in this sort of reasoning.
- According, a using statement should not actually require that the resource be named with a temporary variable, and should not require that the code make use of the reference either: due to side-effects, the resource itself should be considered to be referenced by the using code block, and not safe to garbage collect until the code block terminates, since that could prematurely trigger the Dispose() actions.

I hope I've summarized properly.  For my own purposes, I might take Eric's advice.  On the other hand, this makes what was an elegant piece of code incredibly ugly, and as it turns out, just allocating a temporary variable, while a little bit ugly, does solve the problem (for now).  Plus, as explained above, the C# specification itself probably needs to evolve in this specific respect, so down the road, the Mono behavior may well be declared "incorrect".  So perhaps I won't make my code really gross and disgusting quite yet!